# Refactor database first to code first project

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, refactoring, domain-driven-design

I have a project with existing DB scheme (databased first approach) developed with c# that I want to refactor to code first using ddd

What would be a good way to do it?

- start complete code first project and migrate data to new database
  scheme
- start code first project and use fluent api in order to map domain to existing database scheme
- something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could import the existing schema into code first and carry on from there;

[Entity Framework Code First to an Existing Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Wouldnt that be a reverse code first approach where domain is not in the center?

Comment: Missed the DDD bit. Personally, I would suggest there is still a separation of your data model and your business models and simply map from one to the other.

Comment: I am using this approach http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/04/05/having-the-domain-model-separate-from-the-persistence-model/ in order to use  domain model as a persistance. Do you have any other suggestions?